# Copying mysqldump files from one directory to a backups directory

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, cron

I'm building a shell script that will run nightly with the help of crontab and my script keeps bombing out and giving me the error "Syntax error: word unexpected (expected "do").

The script itself is creating a new directory for each MySQL file it finds in a directory and then copies the files to a created directory from the respective mysqldump directory. Please let me know if I am on the right track with this code and what could be causing my end of file error. I am new to shell scripting and would accept any advice given. If there is a better way to write my code then feel free to help in that respect as well.

```
CDPATH="/backups/mysql"
#
now=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")
#
# Find Directory Name
#
for file in */; do
    dir=${file%/}
    if [[ -e "$dir"]]
    then
        echo "Directory Exists!"
    else
        echo "Directory doesn't exist."
    fi
done
#
# Copy MySQL Databases
#
while [ -d $dir ]; do                                      # Check existing Dirs
    cp -upf /dbase/files/*.sql /backups/mysql/$dir/$now    # If Dir exists, create copy
    if [ ! -d $dir ]; then                                 # If Dir nonexistant create
        mkdir -p $dir
        cp -upf /dbase/files/*.sql /backups/mysql/$dir/$now
    else                                                   # If all else fails just create a copy in /mysql
        cp -upf /dbase/files/*.sql /backups/mysql/$dir/$now
    fi
done
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>1. do not use "then" after "else"

 2. The second line may does not what you want. It just set the variable dir to the string "dir (/backups/mysql/*)"</s>

... obsolete since question has changed.

I assume, files in the following form ...
/dbase/files/db1.sql
/dbase/files/db2.sql
...

... should be backed up to the following destination:

/backups/mysql/db1/2014_11_18/db1.sql

```
#!/bin/bash
BACKUP_DIR="/backups/mysql/"
FILE_DIR=/dbase/files/
now=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")

# setting the input field seperator to newline
IFS=$'\n'

# find db backups and loop over
for file in $(find ${FILE_DIR} -maxdepth 1 -name "*.sql" -type f -exec basename {} \;); do
    # create backup directory:
    mkdir -p "${BACKUP_DIR}${file%.sql}/${now}"

    # copy file over        
    cp "${FILE_DIR}${file}" "${BACKUP_DIR}${file%.sql}/${now}/"
done
```

Convert the script to unix encoding:

```
dos2unix script.sh
```

Comment: I'm still getting "Syntax error: unexpected end of file".

There is a black line automatically being added under "fi" once I save the file. Could this be part of the issue? I've tried just using a "#" to kill the line,  but a new line is always added under that as well.

Comment: If you have more than one db, you have to loop over these.

Comment: What would you suggest using to find if specific directories exist?How would you suggest going about looping through databases? I am new to shell scripting and could use all the help I can get.

Comment: You assumptions are correct. Unfortunately I cannot see if anything  is working since I am continuing to get the word unexpected (expected do) error. I tried hex dumping and restarting the script, but I get the same issues. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Yes I do. I changed from #!/bin/bash to #!/bin/sh as well and that didn't seem to help.

Comment: what version of is installed? bash --version

Comment: bash --version 4.2.37

Comment: i've tested the script from my post on bash 4.2.37 (debian 7.5) and bash 4.2.53 ( fedora 20)!!! ... all ok

Comment: For some rerason I am still getting the "Word unexpected (expected "do")". I deleted the entire file and hand wrote everything in hoping that would solve the issue, but it did not. I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this issue

Comment: Do you edit the file on the Linux machine, or on a windows machine? It could be a encoding issue if you edit the script in windows and copy it over. I've added the command to my post.

Comment: Originally I created the file in Windows. But when I deleted everything and rewrote the script I did it all from bash. I will still try the encoding command that you provided and see if that helps.

Comment: dos2unix is not a recognized command. Assuming the reason for this is because I am on a Linux server. I just made sure all instances of the file were removed from my server and rewrote the script all in linux so the encoding was correct. I now get 'find: missing argument to -exec'

Comment: so we're getting closer! ;) don't miss the whitespace after the curly brackets and be sure that you use a backslash an not a slash after the that whitespace:  ... -exec basename {} \;) ...

Comment: The whitespace after the curly braces was the issue! It successfully ran and created the new date directories, but it did not copy everything over from the source files. cp: cannot copy file"" no such file or directory. I'm assuming since the source files are not in the same folder structure that this is the reason it's not copying correctly. But the script shouldn't care about that.

Comment: may there are whitespaces in the sql file names. so i adapted the script to be aware of that.

Comment: Now I am getting a cannot stat for 10 lines, omitting directory '/dbase/files' for 1 line and cannot stat for 7 more lines. I'm beginning to see why I never wrote my own shell scripts!

Comment: It also appears that the line break you suggest is breaking the file names. I have an eventreceipt.sql file that is just copying over as treceipt.sql.

Comment: i guess you did IFS=$'/n' and not IFS=$'\n' !!!! must be backslash ... the script is working fine for me

Comment: I double checked everything I wrote and it is written correctly. It is writing directories, but not copying any of the files. I can live with wrong file names, but I need the automatic file copy to run at night.

Comment: may you post the ouput of the directory listing: ls -l /dbase/files/